# ArangoDB failed to start

Tags: remote-access, fatal-error, arangodb

I have installed the lastest version of arangodb 3.1.25.

Follow the installation manual , when I start it I get

```
[root@cloudera-manager init.d]# arangod start

2017-07-15T09:40:15Z [19742] INFO ArangoDB 3.1.25 [linux] 64bit, using VPack 0.1.30, ICU 54.1, V8 5.0.71.39, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2017-07-15T09:40:15Z [19742] INFO using SSL options: SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE, SSL_OP_TLS_ROLLBACK_BUG
2017-07-15T09:40:15Z [19742] INFO Starting up with role SINGLE
2017-07-15T09:40:15Z [19742] INFO Authentication is turned on
2017-07-15T09:40:15Z [19742] INFO Authentication system only
2017-07-15T09:40:15Z [19742] INFO Authentication for unix sockets is turned on
2017-07-15T09:40:15Z [19742] INFO file-descriptors (nofiles) hard limit is 8192, soft limit is 8192

    FATAL unable to create database directory 'start': Failed to create directory [start] Permission denied
```

I need to start it on remote so I changed it in the cnfiguration file as follows 
    [console]
    pretty-print = true

```
[server]
endpoint = tcp://0.0.0.0:8529
authentication = true
# username = root
# password =

[javascript]
startup-directory = usr/share/arangodb3/js
```

Running Arangosh I get :

```
Pretty printing values.
Connected to ArangoDB 'http+tcp://0.0.0.0:8529' version: 3.1.25 [server], databa                                                   se: '_system', username: 'root'

Type 'tutorial' for a tutorial or 'help' to see common examples
```

Yet it is not accessible  . 
Where could the problem be from ?
any help would be appreciated,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a folder /opt/arangodb/start :

```
mkdir -p /opt/arangodb/start
chmod 777 /opt/arangodb/start
```

and run this command thsis should work i tested:

```
arangod /opt/arangodb/start
```